# Pygame start button menu

Tags: python, syntax, pygame, program-entry-point

A few days ago I started making my first professional pygame (didn t do any pygame ever before), so for the first time I made a main menu, for the actual game, after that the game, so I have 2 files in that project(main menu and the game).
But after some seconds I realised i don t know how to start the game from the main menu by clicking the START button. SO I NEED SOME HELP......

I will let you  down my main menu code.

```
import pygame
import pygame.freetype
from pygame.sprite import Sprite
from pygame.rect import Rect
from enum import Enum
from pygame.sprite import RenderUpdates

BLUE = (106, 159, 181)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)


def create_surface_with_text(text, font_size, text_rgb, bg_rgb):
   """ Returns surface with text written on """
   font = pygame.freetype.SysFont("Courier", font_size, bold=True)
   surface, _ = font.render(text=text, fgcolor=text_rgb, bgcolor=bg_rgb)
   return surface.convert_alpha()


class UIElement(Sprite):
    """ An user interface element that can be added to a surface """

def __init__(self, center_position, text, font_size, bg_rgb, text_rgb, action=None):
    """
    Args:
        center_position - tuple (x, y)
        text - string of text to write
        font_size - int
        bg_rgb (background colour) - tuple (r, g, b)
        text_rgb (text colour) - tuple (r, g, b)
        action - the gamestate change associated with this button
    """
    self.mouse_over = False

    default_image = create_surface_with_text(
        text=text, font_size=font_size, text_rgb=text_rgb, bg_rgb=bg_rgb
    )

    highlighted_image = create_surface_with_text(
        text=text, font_size=font_size * 1.2, text_rgb=text_rgb, bg_rgb=bg_rgb
    )

    self.images = [default_image, highlighted_image]

    self.rects = [
        default_image.get_rect(center=center_position),
        highlighted_image.get_rect(center=center_position),
    ]

    self.action = action

    super().__init__()

@property
def image(self):
    return self.images[1] if self.mouse_over else self.images[0]

@property
def rect(self):
    return self.rects[1] if self.mouse_over else self.rects[0]

def update(self, mouse_pos, mouse_up):
    """ Updates the mouse_over variable and returns the button's
        action value when clicked.
    """
    if self.rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
        self.mouse_over = True
        if mouse_up:
            return self.action
    else:
        self.mouse_over = False

def draw(self, surface):
    """ Draws element onto a surface """
    surface.blit(self.image, self.rect)


class Player:
""" Stores information about a player """

def __init__(self, score=0, lives=3, current_level=1):
    self.score = score
    self.lives = lives
    self.current_level = current_level


def main():
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
game_state = GameState.TITLE

while True:
    if game_state == GameState.TITLE:
        game_state = title_screen(screen)

    if game_state == GameState.NEWGAME:
        player = Player()
        game_state = play_level(screen, player)

    if game_state == GameState.NEXT_LEVEL:
        player.current_level += 1
        game_state = play_level(screen, player)

    if game_state == GameState.QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        return


def title_screen(screen):
start_btn = UIElement(
    center_position=(400, 400),
    font_size=30,
    bg_rgb=BLUE,
    text_rgb=WHITE,
    text="Start",
    action=GameState.NEWGAME,
)
quit_btn = UIElement(
    center_position=(400, 500),
    font_size=30,
    bg_rgb=BLUE,
    text_rgb=WHITE,
    text="Quit",
    action=GameState.QUIT,
)

buttons = RenderUpdates(start_btn, quit_btn)

return game_loop(screen, buttons)


def play_level(screen, player):
return_btn = UIElement(
    center_position=(140, 570),
    font_size=20,
    bg_rgb=BLUE,
    text_rgb=WHITE,
    text="Return to main menu",
    action=GameState.TITLE,
)

nextlevel_btn = UIElement(
    center_position=(400, 400),
    font_size=30,
    bg_rgb=BLUE,
    text_rgb=WHITE,
    text=f"Next level ({player.current_level + 1})",
    action=GameState.NEXT_LEVEL,
)

buttons = RenderUpdates(return_btn, nextlevel_btn)

return game_loop(screen, buttons)


def game_loop(screen, buttons):
""" Handles game loop until an action is return by a button in the
    buttons sprite renderer.
"""
while True:
    mouse_up = False
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP and event.button == 1:
            mouse_up = True
    screen.fill(BLUE)

    for button in buttons:
        ui_action = button.update(pygame.mouse.get_pos(), mouse_up)
        if ui_action is not None:
            return ui_action

    buttons.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()


class GameState(Enum):
QUIT = -1
TITLE = 0
NEWGAME = 1
NEXT_LEVEL = 2


if __name__ == "__main__":
main()
```

Thank you in advice!!!!

Comment: Please correct the [Indentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html). You can finde some help here [StackOverflow Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting)

Comment: What is the question?  This code looks fine.

Comment: How to open my other python file(game), when i select start in the menu.

Comment: You cannot "open" another pygame file. If you want to run the game in the same pygame window, you have integrate the code. Create some functions (or classes and mehtods) in the 2nd file and call the functions (or methods).

Answer (score 0):

i have two ideas:

1st:
just import it. When you import it it will be executed.

```
import importlib
importlib.import("name of you file without extension") # i dont know the command
```

2nd:
use

> exec()

```
exec(open("filename.py").read())
```

or

```
with open("file.py", "r") as f:
    exec(f.read())
```

ywc